# Check-box value counting in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, counting

This is my code, here there are `6` checkboxes and it call `6` times and each time it make sum of both values, i am passing value like `10,10` than it should be a `20` but it returns `120`,
How can I solve this problem?

```
jQuery('.pricefield input').each( function() {
  var checkedValues = jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    str=this.value;
    source_str = str.substr(str.indexOf("#"));
    keywords = source_str.split (/[\D,]+/);
    val1=keywords[1];
    val2=keywords[2];
    sum+=parseInt(val1, 10)+parseInt(val2, 10);
    alert(sum);
    pricefield_both(sum);
  }).get();
});
```

Comment: ya thats my fault its already + sign

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H3rLw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking at the correct indexes and you need one more position after the #

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3LzfK/)

```
$(function() {
  $('.pricefield input').on("click",function () {
    var sum=0;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        var str=$(this).val().split("#")[1].split(",");
        sum += (parseInt(str[0], 10) + parseInt(str[1], 10));
    });
    pricefield_both(sum); // assuming that function works
  });
});
```

Comment: my code is working well but it make sum of valeus at each time if checkbox is checked or not if not than it continue with previous value and sum it

Answer (score -1):

```
keywords = source_str.split (/[\D,]+/);
val1=keywords[1];
val2=keywords[2];
sum+=parseInt(val1, 10)+parseInt(val2, 10);
```

this code is not good!

try something like bellow!

```
keywords = source_str.split(/[\D,]+/);
val1 = +keywords[1];
val2 = +keywords[2];
sum += val1 + val2;
```

and I suggest you define the variables first so the local variable will not become globally accessble!

```
var str, source_str, keywords, val1, val2, sum;
```

the result is bellow:

```
var str, source_str, keywords, val1, val2, sum = 0;
jQuery('.pricefield input').each( function() {
  var checkedValues = jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    str=this.value;
    source_str = str.substr(str.indexOf("#"));
    keywords = source_str.split (/[\D,]+/);
    val1 = +keywords[1];
    val2 = +keywords[2];
    sum += val1 + val2;
    alert(sum);
    pricefield_both(sum);
  }).get();
});
```

Comment: Apart from defining the vars which is a good thing, what is wrong with the parseInt? Identical behaviour of +keywords[1] and parseInt(keywords[1],10) assuming the regex is correct

Comment: But you said "It is not good" - if it works, it works identically to your code. There is something else going on, for eample that the regex is not picking the correct values. I do not see any structural change in your code.

Comment: Because I actually don't know what's going on! just modify some codes!

Comment: Because your sum is global! not 0 to init!

Comment: so every time your checkbox change should set sum to 0 otherwise the sum will be the sum add all your checked checkbox sum!